# $\int | \nabla |u||^2 = \int |\nabla u|^2$ implies $u=e^{ic} |u|$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Assume $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla |u||^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla u |^2 $.

Is is true that $u=e^{iC} |u|$, where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: I want to exclude the case that the phase is dependent of the spatial variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

$$u = |u|e^{i\theta}$$

then

$$\nabla u = e^{i\theta}\nabla |u| + ie^{i\theta}|u|\nabla\theta$$

and

$$|\nabla u|^2 =  |\nabla|u||^2 + |u|^2|\nabla\theta|^2$$

so the condition, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla u|^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla |u||^2$, given in the question implies $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u|^2|\nabla\theta|^2 =0$. Since the integrand is positive it follows that $|u||\nabla\theta| = 0$ a.e. If $|u| > 0$ it follows that $\theta = $ constant a.e.

Note that we cannot rule out the constant being different in different regions of  $\mathbb{R}^n$ (ref the other answer) without more conditions on $u$.

Comment: Does $H^1$ suffice? It would at least rule out the other answer. I think it suffices, right?

Comment: @Peter I think $u$ of class $C^1$ would suffice (but I'm not totally sure). Then $|u|\nabla\theta$ is forced to be continuous which would rule out $\theta$ 'jumping' to different values.

Answer (score 3):

It's not true as $N=1$ shows. $u=x^3=\mbox{sgn}(x)|x|^3$.

$$|\nabla |u||^2= (3x^2)^2=(3x^2)^2=|\nabla u|^2.$$

Comment: Do you know whether $u\in H^1$ is enough to show that the claim is true?

Comment: @Peter: I'm thinking no still. Couldn't you modify my example to have compact support by connecting it with another cubic polynomial?

Comment: But as long as you are allowed to differentiate, the proof of Winther should work, shouldn't it?